# How can I keep my navbar from going onto multiple lines VANILLA

Tags: html, css

My websites navbar formatting is messed up whenever I scroll my window, Its really annoying and I have tried using different unit scales like percentages, etc.. but none of the stuff I am seing online is working, I would like to keep the same sort of style but have it fit on one line for smaller resolutions without having to change how it looks for larger resolutions (such as pc). thanks.

Fullscreen:
[fullscreen picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Gjz.png)

Smaller resolution:
[smaller resolution picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDKKy.png)

Code:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en">
> <head>
>     <meta charset="UTF-8">
>     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/stylesheets/home.css">
>     <title>Mackseco - A Fun Economy and Trading Website</title>
> </head>
> <body>
>     <div class="navbar">
>         <li id="titleNAVl"><a href="/" id="titleNAV">Mackseco</a></li>
>         <li id="faqNAVl"><a href="/faq" id="faqNAV">FAQ</a></li>
>         <li id="discordNAVl"><a href="/help" id="discordNAV">Discord</a></li>
>         <li id="loginNAVl"><a href="/login" id="loginNAV" style="color:#EDEDED;">Login</a></li>
>     </div>
>     <div class="main">
>         
>     </div>
>
>     <script src="../public/javascripts/home.js"></script>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@700&display=swap');


body
{
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}


.navbar
{
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
.main
{
    margin-top:30px;
}


#titleNAVl, #faqNAVl, #discordNAVl, #loginNAVl
{
    display:inline-block;
}
#titleNAV, #faqNAV, #discordNAV, #loginNAV
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#DA0037;
}
#faqNAV:hover, #discordNAV:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#titleNAVl
{
    margin:2% 45% 0 15%;
    font-size: 2em;
}
#faqNAVl
{
    margin-right:0.8%;
}
#discordNAVl
{
    margin-right:0.8%;
}
#loginNAVl
{
    background-color: #DA0037;
    padding: 0.55em 1.25em 0.55em 1.25em;
    border-radius:0.55em;
}
```

Comment: While margin `45%` will decrease with the screen size the content of the `li` does not. So for example at 0 width you will have your first `li` having its original desktop width (~150px) but margin right of `0` which then exceeds the screensize.
What you should do is seperate left and right nav into their own containers.
Use flexbox or float to align containers left/right in your navbar and then use mediaqueries to make your content smaller (fontSize, padding, margins) if it otherwise exceeds your screensize while beeing rendered on a single line.